# pandas, When RID == 2, VIS2 == ‘sc’, the value of ‘LIMM’ is used to fill RID == 2, VIS2 == ’bl’

Tags: python, pandas

The data I want to process is a .csv file, here is an example

When `RID == 2`, `VIS2 == ‘sc’`, the value of `LIMM` is used to fill `RID == 2`, `VIS2 == ’bl’`

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[2,'sc',13],
                       [2,'m06',23],
                       [2,'m12',4],
                       [2,'bl',np.nan],
                       [3,'sc',6],enter code here
                       [3,'m48',22],
                       [3,'bl',np.nan]],columns=['RID','VIS2','LIMM'])
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Welccome to stackvoerflow, please show your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df2=df.set_index('RID')
f=df2.loc[df2['VIS2'].eq('sc'),'LIMM']
df2['LIMM']=df2['LIMM'].fillna(f)
df=df2.reset_index()
print(df)

   RID VIS2  LIMM
0    2   sc  13.0
1    2  m06  23.0
2    2  m12   4.0
3    2   bl  13.0
4    3   sc   6.0
5    3  m48  22.0
6    3   bl   6.0
```